# Buddy list issue in XMPP Server for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm able to connect to the local server, and also the google talk and display the buddies and chat on the iphone chat client but when I try to get Buddy list of my local server, it return 0.

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence {

// a buddy went offline/online

NSString *presenceType = [presence type]; // online/offline
NSString *myUsername = [[sender myJID] user];
NSString *presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];

if (![presenceFromUser isEqualToString:myUsername]) 
{

 if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"available"]) {

 [_chatDelegate newBuddyOnline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", presenceFromUser, @"ip address"]];

} else if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"unavailable"]) {

 [_chatDelegate buddyWentOffline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", presenceFromUser, @"ip address"]];

}

}
}
```

Here ip address means my server name
Please help!

Please help me!!!

Comment: Could be clear some things up: do you run your XMPP server on your iPhone ("XMPP Server for iPhone")? Do I understand correctly that you *can* see buddies on Google Talk, but you *cannot* see buddies on your local server?

Comment: yup, you are right, i can see talk buddies but not local server's buddies. is there any configuration problem from our server side ?? i can't say what is the exact problem there because don't know more about server side configuration for XMPP server

Comment: Does your server support rosters? Have you tried connecting to your server with another client and seen that that works as expected?

Answer (score 0):

It only tells you when some one comes online or goes offline, according to this code, when any buddy will be online delegate method 'newBuddyOnline' will be fired and when someone will go offline delegate method 'buddyWentOffline' will be fired.
You can get list of all buddies by adding buddies to array when they come online after connecting to xmpp stream